# A program to convert Kg to Lb given a begVal and an endVal, endVal = begVal + 9

Tags: java

I'm writing a program that creates a conversion table from kilograms to pounds. The program should prompt the user for the starting point of the table in kilograms and list 10 entries in increments of 1 kilogram. The conversion is 1 kilogram is equal to 2.2 pounds My output is only showing the Kilograms and not the pounds after conversion.

```
public class kgToLbs1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    
        final double LB_PER_KG = 2.2;


        //Algorithm
        //Open keyboard for input
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        //Prompt user for beginning value and assign to begVal
        System.out.println("Enter beginning value ===>  ");
        int begVal = input.nextInt();

        //Print conversion table headings
        System.out.println("Kilograms     |    Pounds");
        int kg = input.nextInt();
        double lb = input.nextDouble();
        

        //endVal = begVal + 9 
        int endValue = begVal + 9;

        for (int i = 20; i < 30; i++) {
             System.out.printf("%d%n", i, (i * LB_PER_KG));
        }

        //Print conversion table footer //missing

        //Close terminal //missing.
```

**Output looks junky and pounds are not being calculated**

[image: Output]

Comment: What do you mean by "I can't get Lbs output to show correctly"? What it should output? What's being outputted?

Comment: Should've elaborated my question: I'm writing a program that creates a conversion table from kilograms to pounds. The program should prompt the user for the starting point of the table in kilograms and list 10 entries in increments of 1 kilogram. The conversion is 1 kilogram is equal to 2.2 pounds My output is only showing the Kilograms and not the pounds after conversion.

Comment: I've edited my original post, for clarity

Comment: getting this error: java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException;

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html

`System.out.printf("%d%f%n", i, (i * LB_PER_KG));`